# Counterexample for a principal ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

I know: If $R$ is a principal ring, then every nonzero prime ideal is maximal.

What is a counterexample for the converse (opposite direction)?

Comment: Are you asking for a non PID in which every non-zero prime ideal is maximal?

Comment: Yes, i am asking for non PID. I know that a finite integral domain is a field and my idea is to find a ''d'' s.t. ℤ[sqrt(d)] is not principal.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a PID because it doesn't have unique factorization. For instance, $2\cdot 3=6=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$, and one can show that $1+\sqrt{-5}$ is not an associate of either $2$ or $3$.

However, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a [Dedekind domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain) because it is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. Hence every non-zero prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is maximal.